# Purpose of new keyword in creating array in Java

Tags: java, c++, arrays

I want to know why an array created in Java static even when we use the `new` keyword to define it.

From what I've read, the new keyword allocates a memory space in the heap whenever it is encountered during run time, so why give the size of the array at all during definition.

e.g. Why can't

```
int[] array1=new int[20];
```

simply be:

```
int[] array1=new int[];
```

I know that it does not grow automatically and we have `ArrayList` for that but then what is the use of keyword `new` in this? It could have been defined as     `int array1[20];` like we used to do it in C, C++ if it has to be static.

P.S. I know this is an amateurish question but I am an amateur, I tried to Google but couldn't find anything comprehensive.

Comment: `It could have been defined as int array1[20];` It could not, because objects with automatic storage duration don't exist at all in Java. Just by design. (And this is not `static`, static is something completely different)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. The sentence `so why give the size of the array at all during definition` makes no sense to me. You do not need to give the size when you declare a variable of array type. You can just write `int[] array;`, for example. Are you asking about the syntax, or about what an array actually is?

Comment: I think that the OP' reasoning is: `new` is used for allocating dynamic objects (which could grow), but arrays are static (can't grow). So one of them is unnecessary: the `new` or the size of the array.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thanks for finding the time to reply to my query. Yes I extactly mean what VillasV sir says, Thank you for putting it in such a clear way sir, I couldn't do it at all. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be an amateurish question, but it is one of the best amateurish questions you could make.

In order for java to allow you to declare arrays without `new`, it would have to support an additional kind of data type, which would behave like a primitive in the sense that it would not require allocation, but it would be very much unlike a primitive in the sense that it would be of variable size.  That would have immensely complicated the compiler and the JVM.

The approach taken by java is to provide the bare minimum and sufficient primitives in order to be able to get most things done efficiently, and let everything else be done using objects.  That's why arrays are objects.

Also, you might be a bit confused about the meaning of "static" here.  In C, "static" means "of file scope", that is, not visible by other object files.  In C++ and in Java, "static" means "belongs to the class" rather than "belongs to instances of the class".  So, the term "static" is not suitable for describing array allocation.  "Fixed size" or "fixed, predefined size" would be more suitable terms.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `In order for java to allow you to declare arrays without new, it would have to support an additional kind of data type`. You *can* declare and assign arrays without the `new` keyword (e.g. `int[] array = {1, 2, 3};`. I'm not entirely clear, but I think the question is about the language, and why they couldn't have chosen something less verbose and repetitive than `int[] array = new int[3];`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington well, let's see what the OP thinks.  The rest of his wording tells me that he is asking about the inner workings, not about the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in Java everything is an object, including arrays (they have `length` and other data). Thats why you cannot use

```
int myArray[20];
```

In java that would be an `int` and the compiler would be confused. Instead by using this:

```
int[] myArray;
```

You are declaring that `myArray` is of type `int[]` (int array) so Java understands it.

Also in java the length of the array and other data are saved on the array, for this reason you don't have to declare size of array during declaration, instead when creating an array (using `new`) the data are saved.

Maybe there is a better reason that oracle may have answered already, but the fact that in Java everything is an object must have something to do with it. Java is quite specific about objects and types, unlike C where you have more freedom but everything is more loose (especially using pointers).

Answer (score 1):

Since arrays are fixed-size they need to know how much memory to allocate at the time they are instantiated.

ArrayLists or other resizing data structures that internally use arrays to store data actually re-allocate larger arrays when their inner array data 
structure fills up.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of the array data structure is that all its elements are located in the sequential row of memory cells. That is why you can not create array with variable size: it should be unbounbed space vector in memory for this purpose, which is impossible.

If you want change size of array, you should recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of OP's reasoning is:

> `new` is used for allocating dynamic objects (which can grow like, `ArrayList`), but arrays are static (can't grow). So one of them is unnecessary: the `new` or the size of the array.

If that is the question, then the answer is simple:

Well, in Java `new` is necessary for every Object allocation, because in Java all objects are dynamically allocated.

Turns out that in Java, arrays are objects, different from C/C++ where they are not.

Answer (score 0):

All of Java's variables are at most a single 64bit field. Either primitives like

- `integer` (32bit)
- `long` (64bit)
- ...

or references to Objects which depending on JVM / config / OS are 64 or 32 bit fields (but unlike 64bit primitives with atomicity guaranteed).

There is no such thing as C's `int[20]` "type". Neither is there C's static.

What `int[] array = new int[20]` boils down to is roughly

```
int* array = malloc(20 * sizeof(java_int))
```

Each time you see `new` in Java you can imagine a `malloc` and a call to the constructor method in case it's a real `Object` (not just an array). Each `Object` is more or less just a struct of a few primitives and more pointers.

The result is a giant network of relatively small structs pointing to other things. And the garbage collector's task is to free all the leaves that have fallen off the network.

And this is also the reason why you can say Java is copy by value: both primitives and pointers are always copied.

regarding `static` in Java: there is conceptually a struct per class that represents the static context of a class. That's the place where `static` instance variables are anchored. Non-static instance variables are anchored at with their own instance-struct

```
class Car {
    static int[] forAllCars = new int[20];
    Object perCar;
}
...
new Car();
```

translates very loosely (my C is terrible) to

```
struct Car-Static {
    Object* forAllCars;
};
struct Car-Instance {
    Object* perCar;
};
// .. class load time. Happens once and this is referenced from some root object so it can't get garbage collected
struct Car-Static *car_class = (struct Car-Static*) malloc(sizeof(Car-Static));
car_class->forAllCars = malloc(20 * 4);

// .. for every new Car();
struct Car-Instance *new_reference = (struct Car-Instance*) malloc(sizeof(Car-Instance));
new_reference.perCar = NULL; // all things get 0'd
new_reference->constructor();
// "new" essentially returns the "new_reference" then
```